# Redirect from image to script

Tags: .htaccess

please help me with redirect in .htaccess
Iam have simple link

http://domain.com/*test123*/*image-123.gif*

Iam need to redirect from this image to script.

http://domain.com/test.php?company=*test123*?image=*image-123.gif*

My example doesnt work =(

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).\gif$ tracking.php?company=$1&email=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is literally what you have in a .htaccess file, the problem is that you have .\g rather than .g -- that is, you've escaped the 'g' character, rather than the . character.

That is, what you want is:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)\.gif$ tracking.php?company=$1&email=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Also, note that this does not *redirect*, as you say in your question, but it does a transparent rewrite. If you want it to *redirect*, replace the PT with a R in the flag.